# Proving a basic property of integration without using Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the exercise 4.F of Bartle's book: The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure.

4.F Employ Exercise 4.E to establish that if $f,g\in M^{+}(X,\mathcal{F})$ then $f+g\in M^{+}(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $$\int(f+g)d\mu=\int fd\mu+\int gd\mu.$$

Exercise 4.E: Let $f,g\in M^{+},$ let $\omega\in M^{+}$ be a simple function such that $\omega\leq f+g$ and let $\phi_{n}(x)=\sup\{(m/n)\omega(x): 0\leq 
m\leq n, (m/n)\omega(x)\leq f(x)\}.$

Also let $\psi_{n}(x)=\sup\{(1-\frac{1}{n})\omega(x)-\phi_{n}(x),0\}.$

Show that $$(1-\frac{1}{n})\omega\leq\psi_{n}+\phi_{n},\quad\phi_{n}\leq f,\psi_{n}\leq g.$$

I've proved exercise 4.E but I have problems proving 4.F

My attempt:because of the problem 4.E we can assure that $\sup\int\omega d\mu=\int f d\mu.$ In fact, we have the existence of $\int f d\mu$ and $\int g d\mu.$ I think the proof is divided in two parts: proving the inequialities to get the desired equality. I don't get how utilize the previous result to finish this exercise.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: What is the set $M^+$? Positive measurable functions?

Comment: @SeanRoberson It's the set of all nonnegative measurable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega$ is any simple function such that $\omega \leqslant f +g$ then by the result of the previous exercise we have for any $n$, simple functions $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$, such that

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \int\omega \leqslant\int(\phi_n+ \psi_n) = \int \phi_n + \int \psi_n \leqslant \int f + \int g.$$

(You should show that $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ as obtained in the exercise are, in fact, simple functions.)

Hence,

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \int (f+g) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\sup_{\omega \leqslant f+g} \int \omega \leqslant \int f + \int g $$

Since this is true for any positive integer $n$, it follows that

$$ \int (f+g) \leqslant \int f + \int g. $$

To conclude show that

$$\int f + \int g \leqslant  \int (f+g) $$

Hint: Choose any simple functions $\phi \leqslant f$ and $\psi \leqslant g$. Then since $\phi + \psi \leqslant f+g$,

$$\int \phi + \int \psi = \int(\phi + \psi) \leqslant \int(f+g)$$

Comment: Thanks for answer @RRL. I have a doubt: Why is posible that $\int\phi_{n}+\int\psi_{n}=\int\phi_{n}+\psi_{n}$ Are they simple functions?

Comment: Clearly if $\phi_n$ is simple then $\psi_n$ is simple since it is constructed as the positive part of a difference of simple functions.  Now $(m/n)\omega$ is simple.  Can you show that it stays simple when you take the supremum?

Comment: Plus there are other decompositions with simple functions having the same properties.

Comment: Take a simple function $\omega \leqslant f+g$ and any simple function $\phi \leqslant f$. Let $\alpha(x) = \min(\omega(x),\phi(x))$ and $\beta = (\omega-\phi)^+$. Then $\alpha \leqslant f$, $\beta \leqslant g$ and $\omega = \alpha + \beta$.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was proving your observation about supremum of simple functions. Your answer is very clear and helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  I assume you know how to finish the second part to show $\int f + \int g \leqslant \int(f +g)$.

Comment: Yes. Using the fact that $\int (f+g)$ is a superior bound.